# MySQL INSTR with order by matching position

Tags: mysql

I am performing a query to return the values in a table which are substrings contained in a string (str). It is working, but now I want to order the results in the same order they appear in the given string. Also, I want it to return duplicate matches, and keep the order as it is in the main string.

This is the original working query:

[The current resulting order is the order in which the matching fields are stored in the table]

```
select 
    id_ingrediente,
    str,
    root 
from essenzia_ingredientes 
where lang=1 
    AND instr('i\'m listening to music', str) > 0
```

And this is what I am trying to do:

```
select 
    id_ingrediente,
    str,
    root 
from essenzia_ingredientes 
where lang=1 
    AND instr('i\'m listening to music', str) as ord > 0 
ORDER BY ord ASC
```

Of course it is wrong, but I show it to make the idea of what I am trying to achieve clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the column to order by in the select columns, not in the where clause:

```
select 
    `id_ingrediente`,
    `str`,
    `root`,
    instr("i'm listening to music", `str`) as `ord`
from `essenzia_ingredientes` 
where `lang` = 1 
    AND instr("i'm listening to music", `str`) > 0 
ORDER BY `ord` ASC
```

Comment: Thank you Sloan. Just wondering, is MySQL smart enough to reuse the expensive INSTR search? Or will it search twice, once for the search and once for the ordering?

Comment: I believe it will execute it only once, as long as they match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

**OR** you can just put the expression itself in the `order by` instead of creating the column `ord` as below

```
select 
    `id_ingrediente`,
    `str`,
    `root`
from `essenzia_ingredientes` 
where `lang` = 1 
    AND instr("i'm listening to music", `str`) > 0 
ORDER BY instr("i'm listening to music", `str`) ASC
```

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate it. Do you know if MySQL reuses the INSTR search or where I can find the answer to that question?